# i am tryin to undo the specific shapes drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to undo selected shapes drawn on canvas.
The following is the javascript code that I am Implementing 
    //Line
    function line() 
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.onmousedown = startLine;
        canvas.onmouseup = drawLine;
        canvas.onmouseout = stopLine;

```
};
function startLine(e) 
{
    isLine = true;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
}

function drawLine(e) 
{
    if (isLine==true) 
    {
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        context.lineTo(x ,y);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
        cPush();

    }
}  
function stopLine()
{
    isLine = false;
}

//RECTANGLE

function rectangle() 
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.onmousedown = startRectangle;
    canvas.onmouseup = drawRectangle;
    canvas.onmouseout = stopRectangle;
};

function startRectangle(e) 
{
    isRectangle = true;
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y= e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;  
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);    
}
function drawRectangle(e) 
{
    if (isRectangle==true) 
    {
        a= e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        b= e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        var k = Math.min(x,a);
        var l=Math.min(y, b);
        var width=Math.abs(x-a);
        var height=Math.abs(y-b);
        context.strokeRect(k, l, width, height );
        cPush();
    }
} 
function stopRectangle() 
{
    isRectangle = false;
}
var cPushArray = new Array();
var cStep = -1;
function cPush()
{
    cStep++;
    if (cStep < cPushArray.length)
    {
        cPushArray.length = cStep;
    }
    cPushArray.push(document.getElementById("drawingCanvas").toDataURL());
}

function cUndo()
{
    if(cStep > 0)
    {
        cStep--;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
        canvasPic.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(canvasPic,0,0);}
    }
}
function cRedo()
{
    if(cStep < cPushArray.length-1)
    {
        cStep++;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = cPushArray[cStep];
        canvasPic.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(canvasPic,0,0);}
    }
}
```

Here I am drawing lines and rectangles using mouse events. I taken a dropdonw list with line and rectangle as options.
When I select lines only lines has to get undo and when i select rectangle only rectangles should get undo and the same with redo.
Can you please help me in this how to undo and redo the selected shapes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *undo* anything that you've drawn on the canvas. You can only redraw the scene (or a region). So you either clear the whole canvas and draw only the shapes that should be left there, or clear only a region and restore the contents that you need to remain.

I guess you should keep the coordinates of all the shapes that have been drawn in some javascript structure (an array for example) so that you could redraw everything on request. And when something gets deleted - remove it from the structure and redraw the scene (region).